# Как получить названия всех папок С# MailKit

Tags: c#, email, mailkit

Как получить названия всех папок почты с помощью библиотеки MailKit.

```
 public ClientForm(ImapClient client, string email)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            treeViewFolder.HideSelection = false;
            panelFolders.Height = 0;
            _client = client;
            labelNameEmail.Text = email;
            client.GetFolders(/*Тут, как  понимаю, нужно конкретно указывать название папки, а мне нужно узнать название всех папок не зная их названия*/)
            //client.Behavior.AutoPopulateFolderMessages = true;
            //CommonFolderCollection listFolders = client.Folders;
            //_key = new Dictionary<LinkLabel, TreeNode>();
            //foreach (Folder folder in listFolders)
            //{
            //    TreeNode parentNode = treeViewFolder.Nodes.Add(folder.Name);
            //    VisibleLinkLable(folder, parentNode);
            //    if (folder.HasChildren)
            //    {
            //        AddTreeViewFolder(folder.SubFolders, parentNode);
            //    }
            //}
        }
```

Comment: Вопрос будет интересней, если вы добавите ваш код, даже если он ещё нерабочий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень просто:

```
IList<IMailFolder> folders = await client.GetFoldersAsync(client.PersonalNamespaces.First());
List<string> names = folders.Select(t => t.Name).ToList();
```